# Combination of offset, lookup, and apply in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply, lookup, offset

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with two columns: date and price. For each row, I'd like to offset the date by 3 days, and find the price of that date and populate column price_new. Note that the dates are not necessarily in order not complete. See desired output:

```
df_new =
date       price price_new 
2021-01-01 37    N/A
2021-01-05 38    9
2021-01-06 35    42
2021-01-07 9     11
2021-01-08 11    ...
2021-01-11 42
2021-01-12 11

...
```

dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(50)
start_date = "2021-01-01"
end_date= "2021-01-31"
date_range = pd.bdate_range(start=start_date,end=end_date) 
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':date_range, 'price':np.random.randint(5, 50, len(date_range))})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can first `resample` to make sure you have daily and then use `shift()`:

```
new_df = df.set_index("date").resample("D").last().reset_index()
new_df["price_new"] = new_df["price"].shift(-3)
new_df = new_df[new_df["date"].isin(df["date"])].reset_index(drop=True)

>>> new_df
        date  price  price_new
0 2021-01-01   37.0        NaN
1 2021-01-05   38.0       11.0
2 2021-01-06   35.0        NaN
3 2021-01-07    9.0        NaN
4 2021-01-08   11.0       42.0
5 2021-01-11   42.0        NaN
6 2021-01-12   11.0        NaN
```

`df` used:

```
>>> df
        date  price
0 2021-01-01     37
1 2021-01-05     38
2 2021-01-06     35
3 2021-01-07      9
4 2021-01-08     11
5 2021-01-11     42
6 2021-01-12     11
```

Comment: Thanks, `shift` works when the date column is complete but not otherwise (for example if there are holidays and omitted). I'm looking for a solution that is robust if the dates are not complete and also when I want to sometimes shift by #of days as opposed to business days.

Comment: Thanks, please see my example: if you remove date 01-04, your code does not work as intended.